# Edge homomorphisms for Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for a spectrum $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, spectra

> I'm interested in some nice identifications (together with explanations) about the edge homomorphisms in the AHSS for a **spectrum** $X$.

$$\times \times \times $$
Let $X$ be a connective spectrum, as stated in Adams' stable homotopy and generalised homology book for example, for a reduced homology theory $h_*$, there is the AHSS $$H_p(X;h_q(S^0))\Rightarrow h_{p+q}(X)$$ which clearly is a first quadrant spectral sequence. I'm interested in the edge homomorphisms which arise from it, the vertical and the horizontal one.

For a space $Y$ the situation is well-understood and described in the standard literature (Davis & Kirk's book for example), but I can't find anything for a spectrum $X$ (Adams only mentions its existence, not giving any additional details).

**My opinion** is that the situation for the horizontal edge homomorphism might be messy in the spectra case, since it seems to be general knowledge that the differential $$d_2 \colon H_p(X; \Omega_0^{Spin}) \to H_{p-2}(X;\Omega_1^{Spin})$$ which become $$d_2 \colon H_p(X; \mathbb{Z}) \to H_{p-2}(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)$$ is reduction modulo $2$ composed with the dual of the Steenrod square $Sq^2$, therefore not always trivial (as in the case for a space $Y$ where one can analyse the edge homomorphism). What about the vertical one?